# Prove Frobenius norm of projection matrix is 1

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a projection matrix $P$, i.e. $P^2=P$, how do you prove $\|P\|_F=1$, where $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm of the matrix?

Comment: Is the Frobenius norm defined as $\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}|p_{i,j}^2|}$? Is this case, what about $P=I$?

Comment: By submultiplicativity you get $\|P\|_F\geq 1$, but in general, equality does not hold.

Comment: If you want to know more about the Frobenius norm of orthogonal projections, consider the formula $\|P\|_F = \sqrt{tr(P^T P)}$. For orthogonal projection you can use $P^T=P$ and $P^2=P$ and knowledge about the eigenvalues of projections to obtain that the Frobenius norm is equal to the square root of the dimension of the range of $P$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\|P\|_F\ne 1$ in general.

For orthogonal projections, $P$ is positive semi-definite. The eigenvalue (also singular values) $P$ is either 1 or 0. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, if $P$ projects a vector on to a $m$-dimensional subspace, $P$ will have $m$ eigenvalues as 1.

So $\|P\|_F^2=\sum \lambda_i^2=m$. So $\|P\|_F=1$ only if $m=1$, i.e., $P$ project a vector to a given vector.

If the given vector is $v$, then 
$$P=\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}$$
In general, if $P$ project a vector to the column space of a matrix $A$ with full column rank, then
$$P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62213/prove-aata-1at-2-1-when-rank-of-matrix-a-is-n/62229#62229) for a reference.

Comment: @user1551: Do you mean oblique projections? My answer holds for orthogonal projections.

Comment: @user1551: it's a typo, obviously it should be positive semi-definite. thanks anyway.

Comment: @user1551: If $P$ is not Hermitian, its Frobenius norm is always greater than $1$, even if $P$ has rank $1$.